# Sybase IQ: load table with autoincrement column

Tags: sybase, sap-iq

I need to transfer a table from database A to database B, the table has an autoincrement column. The content of the table in the new database has to be identical to the table in the original database, including the values in the autoincrement column.

The following LOAD TABLE, where col1 is the autoincrement column, doesn't work:

```
set identity_insert TableName on;
LOAD TABLE TableName
(col1,col2,col3)
FROM 'file.csv';
```

I get the following error:

*Cannot insert or update Column col1: set option 'identity_insert' to the specific table name containing the identity column to be modified.*

Still, I'm setting the identity_insert option. What's wrong with this command?

Comment: which version of sybase IQ are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
SET TEMPORARY OPTION IDENTITY_INSERT = 'MyTable';
```

This has been discussed on [SCN](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3383909)

Answer (score 0):

DEFAULTS OFF looks like it should be used as an option if you want to ovverride the default identity (autoincrement) value.

see: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1530/doc/html/san1281564935243.html

If that doesn't work, and this is just a one time thing... the simplest way to accomplish this would be to load table into TableName_work that has no autoincrement, then insert the data into your destination via a select statement with identity_insert on.